# How to stop php to execute after getting a false as return in js

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a validator for phone no with js and it is working fine but eve after getting false as return the php code gets executed. how to stop it from executing.

This is my js function

```
function phonenumber(inputtxt){
    var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;
    if(inputtxt.value.match(phoneno))
    {return true;}
    else
    {alert("message");
     return false;}
}
```

This is my html code

```
<form action="get_quote.php" method="post" name="quote" class="quote">
                <font class="label"><input type="text" class="quote" placeholder="Enter Your Name" autocomplete="off" name="name" required/>
                <input type="text" class="quote" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter Your Mobile Number" name="mobile" required/>
                <input type="email" class="quote" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter Your Email Id" name="email" required/><br />
                    </center>
                <div>
                <div class="rest">
                    <input type="radio" id="new" name="condition" class="rest" checked>New<br />
                    <input type="radio" id="mod" name="condition" class="rest"/>Modification
                </div>
                <div class="rest">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="web"  />Website<br />
                    <input type="checkbox" name="android" />Android Application<br />
                    <input type="checkbox" name="ios" />IOS Aplication<br />
                    <input type="checkbox" name="seo" />SEO/SMO<br />
                    <input type="checkbox" name="desktop" />Computer Software<br />
                </div>
                </div>
                <br><center>
                <textarea name="desc" placeholder="Enter Your Description" required></textarea><br /></font>
                <button type="submit" onclick="phonenumber(document.quote.mobile)" class="quote">Get Quote</button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uukx9x8d/1/)**.

Add `return` in `onclick` before function call :

```
<button type="submit" onclick="return phonenumber(document.quote.mobile)" class="quote">Get Quote</button>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're welcome, but it should work check the fiddle in my update.

Comment: its again not working dont know why. there is nothing change in the code

Comment: i think my script in on different php this is why its happening

Answer (score 0):

You can get mobile field value by using this:

```
function phonenumber()
{ 
    var inputtxt = document.getElementsbyName("mobile");
    var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;                 

    if(inputtxt.value.match(phoneno)) 
    {

        return true;
    } 
    else 
    {
        alert("message"); 
        return false;
    } 
}
```

And than no need to pass param in onclick event, use this:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="phonenumber()" class="quote">Get Quote</button>
```

Comment: if i dont give parameter its not even giving the alert message and yeah not helping anyway

Comment: @sahib than chk console is there any error found? And u can also use return as other mate suggest without param

Comment: @sahib... u can try this aswell <form action="get_quote.php" method="post" onclick="return phonenumber()" class="quote">

Comment: i tried both. if i give parameter atleast i am getting alert message which atleast means i get a return value but in without parameter i am not even getting the alert message

Comment: @sahib try this to add onclick function in form tag and remove from button

Comment: @sahib what happened when u click on submit? What u get? Page refresh?